# Why is data not returned from this AngularJS $resource call?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, resources

The server side piece is called correctly by the DEBUGGER code is never reached. Is there something I am missing ?

```
appRoot.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope',
    '$routeParams',
    '$location',
    '$resource',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $resource) {

        var memberResource = $resource('/api/Member/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });

        memberResource.query({
            id: $routeParams.id
        }, function (data) {
            debugger;
        });

    }]);


   // GET api/Member/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(tMember))]
    public IHttpActionResult GettMember(int id)
    {
        tMember tmember = db.tMembers.Find(id);
        if (tmember == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(tmember);
    }
```

Comment: What's the response status code?

Comment: 200. I all the JSON is there. It just never seems to reach the callback (where the debugger is)

Comment: Take a look at the console. There should be an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/docs/api/ngResource.%24resource) says, `memberResource.query` expect an array of results. You are returning a single element, so you should use `memberResources.get`.